# Arduino IR controlled light fade issue

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, light, arduino-c++

Never coded before. I'm having trouble adding a fade feature to this code. I have added a limit of 50. I want the LED to become dimmer the closer the limit. However, the light does cut off after 50 which is what I am also looking for. I am using a SHARP 2Y0A02 F 26 IR sensor to measure the distance.

I have played around with different IF loops and have had no success. When I tried the code without the limit it would fade quite well, however I need the same effect within the limit.

```
#define sensor A0 // Sharp IR 2Y0A02 F 26
int led = 6;
int brightness = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {

analogWrite(led, brightness);

  // 5v
float volts = analogRead(sensor) * 0.0048828125; // value from sensor     * (5/1024)
int distance = 9462/(analogRead(sensor) - 16.92); // Distance in CM
int fade = distance;

delay(1000); // slow down serial port

if (distance <= 50) {
  brightness = -distance;
}
else {
  brightness = 0;
}

Serial.println(distance);   // print the distance
}
```

I expect the light to be very dim at 50 and be gradually brighten when the object is getting closer to 0.

Comment: Perhaps I am missing something, but I don't see how `brightness` is being increased in this code. And for the case where `distance <= 50`, you actually want `brightness -= distance;`. You also don't want `brightness` to be less than 0 because `analogWrite` is supposed to take values between 0 - 255 but the API allows type `int` which allows you to incorrectly provide negative values. See: https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/analog-io/analogwrite/

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I have implemented what you have recommended however, the LED dims gradually for a couple of seconds when the object is stationary. Any tips?

Comment: The `if` and `else` clauses execute regardless of `distance` changing or not. You should keep track of whether or not `distance` has changed (e.g. before the line where you calculate `distance`, do something like `last_distance = distance` then `if(distance != last_distance){ //..now check distance <= 50 and change the brightness }`. In order for you to do this though, you're going to have to declare your variables outside of the `loop` function as they are getting created and destroyed each time it is called. Declare them where you declared `led` and `brightness`.